# What should I focus on early-game in Endless Space?

Tags: endless-space

I think I understand the basic structure of *Endless Space*. That said, the first 50 or so turns in a standard game are fairly crucial. What should my focus be in this early game?

1. What should be the priority? Science? Growth? Improvements? Perhaps colonization above all?
2. Should I invest in as many heroes as possible to get them leveling up early?
3. Is it worthwhile to build early defenses, or neglect defense almost entirely for the first few dozen turns?

Comment: `That said, it is specific` No it isn't. It's the opposite of specific- at best you're asking multiple questions. I'd ask 2 & 3 as separate questions with a bit more detail.

Comment: @Studoku: The overall question is general but applies to a specific situation: the beginning of the game. The three questions were clarifications of the main question at hand. Do you really think they should be split up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should prioritize depends on the game difficulty, your preferred strategy, and your local geography. Nothing more specific can be given in a general answer other than this:

Getting many heroes at the start will kill your economy. All 4x games depend on you husbanding your economic growth better than your opponent. At lower levels of challenge/skill level, a general outgrowing of your opponent is all that is needed (ie, settle worlds/lands faster than they do). At high levels of challenge/skill level, you need to concentrate your economic growth in a particular area so you can outgrow your opponent in that area, and then leverage that advantage to win.

So, in short, only get your heroes at the rate you can afford them.